# Halo around coloured glass bottle

Tags: color

I have a product picture of a bottle which I need to cut out...
I've created a clipping path and a mask to cut out but I have an awkward greyish halo that makes it look awful when put on a dark background. How can I make the same pinkish colour of the bottle continue smoothly out right to the edge?

I've tried selective colour, replace colour, brightness/contrast, hue/saturation adjustment layers with various selection techniques and can't seem to get anywhere close. I'm either doing something wrong or missing an awesome tool to add to my (very small repertoire). I do not know what software I am using.

If anyone can help, you'd save me a lot of hours and anguish!

[image: Bottle Example]

[image: Grey Halo]

Photoshop CS6

Comment: Where did the greyish halo come from? I would go back to the original image and make sure its borders are the color I want. If they aren't I would paint over them.

Comment: The Halo's are from the original image - the photo was taken on a pale grey background in a studio and the glass throws it naturally...

Comment: I'm sure I can help you except I'm not positive what you're after. Do you want it to be darker or just have a red hue on it?

Comment: Its clearly a reflection of a light coloured background or light box. Yes it looks terrible. If this is for the manufacturer and they have insisted on that background colour, I would insist it is re-shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your bottle without a background in 2 layers In the top layer cut the edges off  by using a 10 pix contracted selection with 5 pix feather. It makes the edges gradually transparent.

The middle layer has the bottle as is, but with reduced opacity. Here the opacity is 33%, but try also smaller walues. A few % is enough to make the bottle solid.

At the bottom is the solid dark background.

[image]

This simulates the reflection of the current background. Another trick is to make the edges of the glass (=the shoulders and below) dark. It does not work with the metal on the neck and cap.

See an example. The middle layer is a black bottle, but its partially transparent to make the effect subtle. There's also a layer mask to keep the black out of the neck, cap and bottom edge.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was hoping for - thank you so much!